# How can I fix "The 'pathlib' package is an obsolete backport of a standard library package and is incompatible with PyInstaller"?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pyinstaller

I am using Python 3.9.16. When I try to build an application like so:

```
(base) G:\>pyinstaller --onefile grp.py
```

I get an error that says:

```
The 'pathlib' package is an obsolete backport of a standard library package and is incompatible with PyInstaller. Please remove this package (located in C:\Users\alpha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages) using conda remove then try again.
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pyinstaller, as well as upgrading conda, but none of this helped.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What's your question? Does doing what the error message told you to do not work?

Comment: Have you updated `pyinstaller` itself lately?

Comment: Yes i uninstall and installed again, updated conda a well

Comment: conda update conda. conda update python. conda update pathlib

Comment: Already done and same error message

Comment: You don't want to update conda's version of `pathlib`, you want to remove it completely.  It's now a standard, built-in Python module.

Comment: How please @jasonharper?

Comment: I would assume that the command is `conda remove pathlib` (sorry, not a conda user myself).

Comment: didnt work @jasonharper

Comment: the correct command would be `conda uninstall pathlib`

Comment: I can't understand. The error told you to uninstall pathlib. So why did you not try uninstalling pathlib, and why did you try reinstalling pyinstaller and upgrading conda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `conda remove pathlib` can't find the package, go to the `lib` folder and delete a folder called `path-list-....`.

Comment: Deleting the "pathlib ..." folder from location "C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\lib\site-packages" worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: the correct command would be `conda uninstall pathlib`

Answer (score 10):

Try downgrading pyInstaller to 5.1 (from 5.8). Then it will not be necessary to remove pathlib.

Answer (score 2):

If `conda remove pathlib` doesn't work, try using `pip uninstall pathlib` to remove the package.

Comment: Neither of these work for me.  We have a sequestered repository that (evidently) doesn't have the repodata.json file needed.  I found a 'new' pathlib called pathlib2 (pypi.org/project/pathlib2) which I installed, but it doesn't replace or remove pathlib and pyinstaller still wants to use a 'good' pathlib.

Answer (score 1):

Try working in a new `Environment`. Working in Anaconda's default Environment[base(root)] could cause some annoying errors, especially compatibility issues, since it has quite a few packages installed by default. A new Environment can avoid those problems by not including those packages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Conda environment and use that one instead of the base environment. The new enviorment will not have pathlib installed, which solves the problem.

Comment: This is a fine idea, but illustager [beat you to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76827177/).

Answer (score -1):

Try removing Pathlib using `conda remove pathlib`. After this, `import pathlib` etc. should still work and Pathlib should still be available in the Anaconda environment:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I've used py2exe in the past and has served me well since the question is "how to convert a .py into .exe" (paraphrased).

Checkout https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/
See Tutorial https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Answer (score -2):

The error message you received suggests that the 'pathlib' package installed in your Anaconda environment is causing compatibility issues with PyInstaller. As a result, PyInstaller is unable to create a standalone executable from your Python script.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This response merely restates the error message. I'd suggest you just remove it.

Answer (score -2):

pip install pyinstaller==5.1 works for me

Comment: Please don't repeat answers